# google sheets scripts not updating for all users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has custom scripts in it. It is used as a template and is replicated for each project we have. In order to have the sheet be updated in the future with new scripts, I created a "Library" document and published the scripts as a library.

Everything works fine for me the owner of the document. If I update the library script sheet document it shows up correctly on an older sheet document. However other people in the company do not see the update.

Here is the script in the normal document. (I've removed other functions not relevant to the issue)

```
// all functions can be found in Customer_notes_Library spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*********

function onOpen() {
  CustomerLibrary.onOpen();
}
```

Here is the script in the Library Template

```
devmode:false

// This will run when sheet is opened and add a drop down menu for us to add custom global functions. We have added a Sonicwall Setup Menu option
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .createMenu('Realm Custom Scripts')
        .addItem('DHCP Bash Script', 'runBuildDHCPBashScript')
        .addItem('IP Adress Input', 'runBuildDHCPIpAdressInput')
        .addItem('Wire Device Input', 'runBuildDHCPIpAdressInput')
        .addItem('Client Music Request', 'runClientMusicFormRequest')
        .addToUi();
}
```

These drop-down menus are not updating for other users but is updating for me the owner.

I believe the issue is the onOpen function and there needs to be some way for the user to reauthorize access to the sheet that has the library in it after the scripts in the library have been updated.

I see someone had a similar issue here. But I'm unable to follow the solution.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BJd8zRYD1qU;context-place=forum/docs

I also read that setting devmode to false might be helpful, not sure if I am doing that correctly or not.

Any help and if need further detail please let me know.

Comment: Do those people have authorized EDIT access on the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes. I’ve tried for both sheets the one with the library and the one that points to the library.

Comment: this might actually be the answer. Putting this here until confirmation from multiple users it worked. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/cvJm8BwXtYY;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/script$20works$20for$20owner$20but$20not$20other$20users

Comment: I was never able to get this to work. Made this an Add-On to bypass al the permissions issues.